# How do I get different values from the same variable in XML using XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

XML:

```
<message code="100" description="checkSnr">
  <string name="id"/>
  <string name="serialNr"/>
</message>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="machine/events"> 
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="message/@code"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="message/string/@name"  />
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="message/string/@name"  />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So here's my Problem. My XSL-File is supposed to detect the value "id" and the value "serialNr", but my Output is "id" x2. I know it is only Logical but how can I actually Change my XSL so it gives me both of the values? (by the way, in the XML there are parts, where the variable "string Name" is used like 4 times) I thought of rewriting the XML with a Loop so that the Name variables get renamed into name1, name2, name3 and so on, but I can't figure out how to do that. I use Java as a converter if you can think of any Solutions in Java.
My Output Format is .CSV if that matters.

(any other tips on improving the XSL are appreciated aswell)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you have 2 **empty** `string` tags.

I suppose, your XML should have the following shape:

```
<message code="100" description="checkSnr">
  <string name="id">1234</string>
  <string name="serialNr">5678</string>
</message>
```

Then you shoud read both `string` tags using `name` attribute with particular value **as a predicate**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="machine/events"> 
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="message/@code"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="message/string[@name='id']"  />
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="message/string[@name='serialNr']"  />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer!

I actually thought the same about the shape kind of thing.
It'll be next up to get those values and then use them in XSL, so your answer helped me out already.
My problem at the moment is, I have to get the main structure out of the xml.
Desired CSV looks like
     <STX>code;id;serialNr<CR><LF>
I'll have to add the <STX>... later on. But I need to get "code;id;..." somehow out of my XML to get the structure as CSV.